# mongo Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongo-shell

I am trying to sort a field on a collection in mongo, here is the query,

```
db.results.find({}).sort({'date':1})
```

got an error:

```
Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM
```

I tried to create an index,

```
db.results.createIndex({'date':1})
```

and then executed the above `sort`, got an error in `Robomongo 0.9.0`,

```
The specified text was not found
```

How to conduct the sort properly and also how to get a ISO date range from the field `date` in this case.

ps a sample dates

```
2017-06-29 00:00:00.000Z
2017-06-27 00:00:00.000Z
2017-06-28 00:00:00.000Z
2017-06-30 00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: The first error is an expected error when the sort operation consumes more than 32 mb. Now you have created an index,  does the query run successfully in the mongo shell?

Comment: @Euclides nope, the `Robomongo` just showed `The specified text was not found` in its UI

Comment: I hope this link can address your problem and why you are getting that error:  https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/171

Comment: And to get a ISO data range you can use the $gt, $lt, $gte, $lte operators, example:  db.results.find({ 'date': {$gt: ISODate("2001-02-01T06:10:00Z"), $lt:  ISODate("2001-02-01T07:32:00Z")}},{'_id':0,'date':1}).sort({'date': 1}); Hope that makes sense.